# How to turn on LED that's attached to an arduino via BLE from ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

Here is the scenario. I have an esp32, 2 led's and a ios example app I found online [here](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy-on-ios-ada3090fc9cc). Currently If I press a button on my esp32 it notifies the ios app to display "1", if pressed again it displays "0". This works perfectly.

The tricky part is that this ios app allows me to send a write command to the esp32. I'd like to make it so if '1' is sent LED A turns ON and LED B turns OFF, then LED A OFF and LED B ON when 0 is sent. I am unable to do this though. Try as I might I can't figure out where in the chain of this project something is wrong. Maybe the code on the esp32 or maybe the app i'm unsure.

Here is my arduino code. (There is more to the code not mentioned, I actually have 4 led's but I only want to turn on 2 certain ones when a write command is sent).

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic = NULL;
bool deviceConnected = false;
bool oldDeviceConnected = false;
boolean oldState = LOW;
uint32_t value = 0;

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
};

void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
  deviceConnected = false;
}
};

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();

      if (rxValue.length() > 0) {
        Serial.print("Received Value: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++) {
          Serial.print(rxValue[i]);
         }

        Serial.println();

        if (rxValue.find("1") != -1) {
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(27, LOW);
        }
        else if (rxValue.find("0") != -1) {
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);
          digitalWrite(27, HIGH);
        }
      }
    }
};

const int bt1 = 14;
boolean bt1g = true;
int bt1t = 0;


void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(33, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(27, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bt1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  BLEDevice::init("ESP32");
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                    );

  pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");
}

void loop()
{


  if (bt1g) {
    if (digitalRead(bt1) == LOW ) {
      bt1t = (bt1t + 1) % 2;
      Serial.println(bt1t);
      bt1g = false;

    }
  }
  if (!bt1g) {
    if (digitalRead(bt1) == HIGH) {
      bt1g = true;
    }
  }

  if (bt1t == 0) {
    digitalWrite(15, LOW);
    digitalWrite(33, HIGH);

  }
  }

  boolean newState = digitalRead(15);

  if (deviceConnected) {
    if (newState != oldState) {
      if (newState == LOW) {
        pCharacteristic->setValue("1");

      }
      else {
        pCharacteristic->setValue("0");

      }
      pCharacteristic->notify();
    };

    oldState = newState;

  }
  delay(50);
}
```

It looks like the entire code for the ios app is too long to submit to this post so [here](https://github.com/yostane/iOS-BlueCap-Example) is the github

I'm really unsure and stuck in a rut. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I was attempting to look through your code but find it superfluous.  In order to receive a write command from your iOS apo, you don't need any of the code in the loop. The characteristics callback on write function will trigger when data is sent from the connected app.  The fact that your also trying to manipulate these outputs in the loop is confusing.  Why not simplify your example removing what is happening in your loop and try and post again. I'd like to help but have trouble following your logic

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you are not discovering the correct characteristics? It looks like you only have one service and one characteristic.

Comment: Would I need more than one characteristic? A user [here at the bottom](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=509035.0;nowap) indicated possibly you can do multiple led's in one characteristic.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I am not completely clear on what the code is on the Client side (iOS) or the device side (esp32?)

You saying you'd like to make a single service/characteristic control the stats where either light A-on and B-off or A-off and B-on.

If that is the case then writing to that characteristic should do the trick. If that doesn't work it seems to be on the hardware side.

You can debug by using a third party ble app like 'LightBlue', instead of debugging both your app and hardware at the same time